# Optimizing performance in android graphics

Tags: android, performance, graphics

I'm creating a maps application that needs to display a very large bitmap of a world map which is bigger than most screens and consumes a lot of memory.

To solve the problem, I'm using a similar idea to google maps and its app by splitting the map into smaller 256x256 pieces and then calculating the pieces that fall in the view area which on my device is 12 pieces at any one time.

The pieces are all stored in the assets folder which get loaded using the assetmanager and then decoded into a bitmap using bitmapfactory and then drawn onto my views canvas.

This is very slow and even after going further in the literature and having it run in a seperate thread, the graphics are jerky when scrolling around to new locations.

How do other games and apps (like google maps) dispaly graphics with such smooth scrolling?

Comment: make webview length,height=wrap,fill parent

Comment: But webview is used to dispaly webpage data off the internet. I'm attempting to load it from the device itself so that an internet connection is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts it seems that the problem was with the reading from the assets folder.  I solved the problem by calculating the maximum number of map pieces visible at one time from the users screen size.  The Draw procedure first searches for pieces in the array that are now off the screen and nulls the slots. It then looks for pieces that are now visible and loads them into an empty slot.

The app then uses the array as a source of data and it has reduced the assets folder reads down to 6 as opposed to the direct method loading 20 pieces per Draw.

The game now runs with the speed of popular mobile games!